# Check for adjacent cells in a 5x6 matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I have a 5x6 matrix which I have created using individual buttons in Java Swing.

I have named them similar to a chess board, as A1 to F5 from top left to bottom right.

Now, I want to allow the user to click only a given number of adjacent buttons, either horizontally or vertically.

Say, the value is 4. So, the user must be able to select only 4 buttons anywhere in the matrix which are next to each other vertically or horizontally.

For eg. D2, C2, B2, A2 if chosen vertically.
Or, maybe D1, D2, D3, D4 if chosen horizontally.

What would be the algorithmic way of achieving this functionality for any set of buttons in the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code, I added some comments to make it more clear.

***Please note that the array in the code should be sorted***

**Logic**

Horizontal

```
A1 => 01
A2 => 02
A3 => 03
A4 => 04

So A2 - A1 = 1
```

Vertical

```
A1 => 01
B1 => 11
C1 => 21
D1 => 31

So B1 - A1 = 10
```

**Code:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] spots0 = { "A1", "B1", "C1", "D1" };
        String[] spots1 = { "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4" };
        String[] spots2 = { "A1", "B1", "B2", "B3" };

        System.out.println(isCorrect(spots0) ? "correct" : "incorrect");
        System.out.println(isCorrect(spots1) ? "correct" : "incorrect");
        System.out.println(isCorrect(spots2) ? "correct" : "incorrect");
    }

    public static boolean isCorrect(String[] spots) {
        int NONE = -1;
        int HORIZONTAL = 1;
        int VERTICAL = 2;

        int pattern = NONE; //BY DEFAULT NONE

        for (int i = 0; i < spots.length - 1; i++) {

            //difference between 2 consecutive element in spots[]. If A2 - A1 = 1, and B1 - A1 = 10
            int diff = toNum(spots[i + 1]) - toNum(spots[i]);

            if (diff == 1) { // if HORIZONTAL
                if (pattern == NONE) // if the first time
                    pattern = HORIZONTAL; // set pattern to vertical, this is used for later to check if any illigal change happen
                else if (pattern == VERTICAL) { //if it was Vertical and changed, then error
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (diff == 10) { // if VERTICAL
                if (pattern == NONE) // if the first time
                    pattern = VERTICAL; // set pattern to horizontal, this is used for later to check if any illigal change happen
                else if (pattern == HORIZONTAL) { //if it was Horizontal and changed, then error
                    return false;
                }

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static int toNum(String s) {
        // A1 => 01 , B1 => 11, C2 => 22
        return Integer.parseInt("" + ((int)s.charAt(0) - 'A') + s.charAt(1));
    }
```

Comment: @KanishkaGanguly I just noticed that this question is still open for answers. May you please mark it solved if the above answer is correct. Thank you